# Problem with git (warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1, etc..)

Tags: bash, github, git-bash, git-for-windows, git-shell

Wanted to learn git, so i donwloaded it and wrote some things.
When I opened it today, it "crashed" my windows 10 and then showed a few tenths of errors. I tried to work in visual studio code, but when i write some git command like `ls-la` it shows me that it doesnt not recognize this command. It is probably that i am in powershell terminal.

Here are some pics:

**I open the git**

[image]

**Windows crashes because git consumes too much ram**

[image]

**I try to close the git but this window pops out**
[image]

**And git after a while loads like normal**

[image]

**ERROR MESSAGES:**

```
/usr/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
      0 [main] bash 4187 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68440 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1040411 [main] bash 4187 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68468 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (68508) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   5744 [main] bash (68508) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3233984 [main] bash 4187 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68508 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 55808 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (55876) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    421 [main] bash (55876) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
1188122 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 55876 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (56044) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    600 [main] bash (56044) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3381615 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 56044 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (56208) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    419 [main] bash (56208) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
7600315 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 56208 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (56728) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    455 [main] bash (56728) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4189 dofork: child -1 - forked process 56728 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (57056) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    390 [main] bash (57056) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4190 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57056 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (57196) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   1304 [main] bash (57196) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
1377111 [main] bash 4190 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57196 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (57420) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   1044 [main] bash (57420) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57420 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (57688) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   1326 [main] bash (57688) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
1272058 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57688 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3288717 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - forked process 58096 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7295303 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe', errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (59256) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    474 [main] bash (59256) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4192 dofork: child -1 - forked process 59256 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1041835 [main] bash 4192 dofork: child -1 - forked process 59464 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4196 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68460 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (68516) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    352 [main] bash (68516) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4197 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68516 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (63444) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    308 [main] bash (63444) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4207 dofork: child -1 - forked process 63444 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1038461 [main] bash 4207 dofork: child -1 - forked process 63756 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (64068) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    423 [main] bash (64068) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3258595 [main] bash 4207 dofork: child -1 - forked process 64068 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - forked process 64404 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1036326 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - forked process 44524 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3060575 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - forked process 64712 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7078056 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe', errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (44944) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    418 [main] bash (44944) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 44944 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
      0 [main] bash (52852) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    496 [main] bash (52852) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3150088 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 52852 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (22312) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    349 [main] bash (22312) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
7943439 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 22312 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (19268) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    344 [main] bash (19268) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
13178493 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 19268 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (23236) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    379 [main] bash (23236) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
21902642 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 23236 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

GRZEG@DESKTOP-25LL6A3 MINGW64 ~
$
```

I try to use vscode but as I said, the `ls -la` command is not recognized

[image]

**bash.bashrc file**
[image]

Comment: Check for line in the file  `.bashrc` that launches `bash`, and remove or fix it. That will cause bash to keep launching `bash`, which sources `.bashrc`, which launches bash, etc. Shell level 1000 means this happened 1000 times. The vscode terminal looks like powershell. `ls` is usually aliased to the powershell equivalent `Get-ChildItem`, where the flags `-la` are probably invalid.

Comment: I found bash.bashrc file in C:\Program Files\Git\etc but I have absolutely no idea which line is launching bash.

Comment: @dan I added the contents of this file to the pos

Comment: Maybe look at `/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc`. I thought maybe you added a bug here. But if you didn't change anything, try reinstalling, and reading the install/start guide closely. Also, I can highly recommend WSL as an alternative to git-bash.

Comment: @dan I uninstalled git completely and then installed it, but that still didn't work. Actually, I only want to use git in visual studio code, so what would I have to change in the settings for git to work properly in vsc?

Comment: I don't use vscode much, I'm not sure. I'm sure you can google it. One other thing I would try is to find another method to launch git-bash. For example `bash.exe` in powershell or start menu.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure (assuming VSCode 1.62.3 and Git For Windows 2.34.1) that:

- you don't have a `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` at all (to avoid any side effect from its content)
- you have added to your PATH (before launching VSCode) `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` (which includes `ls.exe`)
- you open in VSCode a Terminal / Git bash session, or even a regular CMD session, not a Powershell one.

Then ls should be recognized, and no fork process should happen.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: @Gorge Would the latest 1.63/1.64 VSCode, with the latest Git 2.35.1 help?

Comment: how can i delete completely git and install lastest verision ?

Comment: it didnt help                            .

Comment: @Gorge Simply type `git update-git-for-windows`

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: can i write that command in cmd ?

Comment: @Gorge To upgrade, yes: you can try it.

Comment: i reinstalled and i am having crash in a second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241588/discussion-between-vonc-and-gorge).